# Using proxy with sockets in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, proxy

I have some PHP code in which XML data is being passed between server and client using sockets. `socket_create( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP )`, `socket_read()`, `socket_write()` are the functions being used to pass XML and not HTTP requests.

Now if I want to use a proxy for client to use to connect through to the server, how can I do that in PHP?

I am new to sockets and from what I have gathered, there exists this library https://github.com/clue/php-socks which I don't fully understand right now but the idea is to setup the middleman using the same library which is essentially the proxy in this case. How would I go about using a SOCKS4/5 proxy obtained from https://www.socks-proxy.net/ or paid ones? Is the above mentioned library the only option? Feels like PHP should have something built in already.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but it's a bit long.

> Feels like PHP should have something built in already

I'm struggling to imagine why it should. PHP is a language designed for serverside web development. Proxies are a client side technology. Having said that the curl extension has comprehensive support for HTTP proxies.

There is no single proxy protocol. Certainly SOCKS and HTTP are the most visible protocols for proxies but there are lots more. Was there a specific reason for choosing SOCKS?

If it were me I would just setup transparent port forwarding using iptables (Linux) or a socat instance or haproxy (Unix, MSWindows).

Comment: 1) Since PHP has socket_* functions, it feels like PHP core devs would have considered proxy support and not leave it out, unless they had a good reason for doing so. 2) SOCKS proxy because I am working with streams here (am I not?) 3) iptables or server based won't work since the client is not fixed to just one server, it has to be application based.

Anything that you can point me to for more research or a solution or a straight forward code sample?

Comment: I am struggling a bit to associate meaning to your response.  Regarding 1) since PHP supports sockets, additional network abstraction can be implemented in PHP code as demonstrated by the product you cited rather than in PHP's code. 2) If you mean that you are not using a standard protocol such as HTTP or SMTP....then, yes, that excludes protocol specific proxies, but not all the other ways of rerouting traffic . I don't know what you mean by 3

Comment: 1) I am just having a hard time understanding the need to use an external library for proxy support whereas curl has proxy support built in, but I guess that's ok if this is the only route. 2) SOCKS proxy would work with any protocol, so figured it would work with my use case 3) This code has to be packaged and distributed, so proxy support has to be built in application itself

Comment: Use a transparent proxy.